# In jQuery, how do I apply .not to $(this) as well as other elements?

Tags: jquery

So, I have a html document with divs that have classes `class1` and `class2`. What is the proper jQuery syntax to use if I want to apply a certain function to all divs except the one that I just clicked (i.e., `$(this)`) and all those with `.class1` and `class2`? (Incidentally, `$(this)` need not possess either of these classes.)

I've tried various combinations, such as

```
$('div').not($('.class1,.class2',this)).addClass('class3');
```

but none seem to work.

Many thanks!

Comment: Where are you using this code? Need to know context of `this`

Comment: What about `$('div').not('.class1').not('.class2').not(this).addClass('class3')`?

Comment: Is there an event that you're binding this to? In other words when do you need the `class1, class2` added to all divs except `this` div

Comment: I'm binding it to a click event. So, `$('div').click(function(){ stuff with .not })`. What I want is, if I click an arbitrary div, that class3 is added to every other div, except the present one, and those with class1 or class2.

Comment: It would probably be better to use $("div:not('.class1,.class2')")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can string together `.not` functions.  Refer to the following example.

```js
$(".clickme").click(function () {
  $('div').not('.class1, .class2').not(this).addClass('class3');
});
```

```css
.class3 {
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="class1">class1</div>
<div class="class2">class2</div>
<div>will light up</div>
<div class="clickme">Click me</div>
```

Comment: @Rüzgar  That's technically not right.  I think you'd be adding them to the selector.  Additionally, it must be a css selector, like `add('.class1')`.

Comment: `var $el = $(this).add('.class1').add('.class2'); $('div').not($el).addClass('class3');`

Comment: @Rüzgar  Thanks for the input.  I think I will keep my current answer, but you're idea is a perfectly valid option.

Comment: your answer is better :)

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful to know!

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of ways you can do this in jQuery. The first option is the one you're after however if you don't need to use `this` and hardcode in the elements directly, you can use `not` in CSS as well. I've included it as it's worth noting.

### [***.not()***](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

```js
$("div").not(".class1").css("background-color", "red");

$("div").not(".class1").not(".class2").css("font-size", "24px");
```

```html
<div class="class1">Test 1</div>

<div class="class2">Test 2</div>

<div class="class3">Test 3</div>
```

[***CodePen Example***](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mmeYJB)

You can use the `.not()` function to select an element and modify it by itself or chain them together one after the other which is what you need. You can't add this inside the parenthesis with another class because jQuery will think they're linked together and not treat them as separate rules.

### [***:not***](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) (*in jQuery*)

```js
$("li:not(:last-of-type)").css("background-color", "blue");
```

Another option using CSS if you don't need to use `this` to specify the current selector as a variable. Not ideal, but is an option.

### [***:not***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:not) (*in CSS*)

```css
div:not(.orange) { color: green; }
```

The same as above, but again requires hard coding in the selector name. Not ideal but another option for native CSS support.

Comment: Thanks, also very useful to know!